# Replacing `imp.load_source` in Python 3.12

Tags: python-3.x, migration, chromium, python-importlib

I am trying to build Electron (basically Chromium) on Fedora Rawhide. The distro (as of 2023) ships with Python 3.12. [One of the scripts ran during build](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/108.0.5359.215:components/resources/protobufs/binary_proto_generator.py?q=binary_proto_generator.py) fails due to a [missing `imp` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/98040). The offending function is:

```py
  def load_module(self, fullname):
    """Loads the module specified by |fullname| and returns the module."""
    if fullname in sys.modules:
      # Per PEP #302, if |fullname| is in sys.modules, it must be returned.
      return sys.modules[fullname]

    if (not fullname.startswith('google.protobuf.') or
        not self._module_exists(fullname)):
      # Per PEP #302, raise ImportError if the requested module/package
      # cannot be loaded. This should never get reached for this simple loader,
      # but is included for completeness.
      raise ImportError(fullname)

    filepath = self._fullname_to_filepath(fullname)
    return imp.load_source(fullname, filepath)
```

How can i replace this usage of `imp` using only libraries available on a Linux distro? (Bonus points if the solution is backward compatible — Chromium needs to be buildable with Python as old as 3.6, any patch requiring new features will be likely rejected by upstream)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the same problem recently.

The possible answer is:

```py
import importlib.util
import importlib.machinery

def load_source(modname, filename):
    loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(modname, filename)
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(modname, filename, loader=loader)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    # The module is always executed and not cached in sys.modules.
    # Uncomment the following line to cache the module.
    # sys.modules[module.__name__] = module
    loader.exec_module(module)
    return module
```

It's from [official importlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html?highlight=load_source#imp)

In this [official issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/104212) you can find different solutions.